# Isomorphism between a finite group that all non-identity elements have order 2 and $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group that all non-identity elements have order 2. I know that we can prove that $G$ is abelian, and then by the structural theorem of finite abelian groups we can show that $G$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^{n}$ for some $n$.

My question is:
Can we construct an explicit isomorphism between $G$ and $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^{n}$ to show that they are isomorphic, without relying on the structural theorem? I hope the approach can be completely group-theoretic, without using knowledge in, say, vector space theory.

My attempt is to observe elements in $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^{n}$ are strings of 0s and 1s, and they look like binary representation of natural numbers. So if we enumerate $G =\{ g_0, g_1, ..., g_{n-1}\}$, with $g_0$ being the identity, then we can map $g_i$ to the corresponding binary representation of the natural number $i$ in the group $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^{n}$. But it seems to fail.

Could anyone provide some ideas?

Comment: Use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

We will write the group additively.

Let $a\in G$, $a\neq0$. Let us choose the largest subgroup $H$ among the subgroups of $G$ not containing $a$. Then $G=H\oplus \langle a\rangle$ (why?). Since $|H|<|G|$ we obtain by induction that $G=A_1\oplus A_2\oplus\ldots\oplus A_k$, where $|A_i|=2$.